# Python Subprocess ping -h Returns Exit Status 2

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess, ping

I want to capture `ping -h` output using Python, it results in exit status 2.

I am working on a Linux host.

```
 import subprocess
 
    
    class Network_Ping ():
      
    

        def Get_Ping_Help(self):
            res = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-h'], universal_newlines = True)
            print (res)
   
    def main():
     obj = Network_Ping()
     obj.Get_Ping_Help()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

This is the **output**

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Network_Ping.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "Network_Ping.py", line 35, in main
    obj.Get_Ping_Help()
  File "Network_Ping.py", line 20, in Get_Ping_Help
    res = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-h'], universal_newlines = True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-h']' returned non-zero exit status 2.`
```

The command seems to execute normally on the shell. What is the cause of this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: This is normal. Try typing `echo $?` in the shell after you run `ping -h`.

Comment: The shell doesn't tell you when programs return non-zero exit status.

Comment: Use `subprocess.run()` if you don't want it checking the exit status. That's what `check` in the name means.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I thought `check_output` is to capture the output of the shell.

I have replaced it with `subprocess.run(['ping', '-h'],capture_output=True, text = True)`.

Comment: It does both. `check` means check the exit status, and `output` means capture the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Barmar solution

It is a normal behavior for ping, but the shell does not show it; Shell does not return exit status. We can see it by:

`ping -h;echo $?`

To avoid checking the exit status, we can replace `subprocess.check_output()` with `subprocess.run()`

and to capture the output successfully.

```
   res = subprocess.run(['ping', '-h'],capture_output=True, text = True)

   print(res.stderr)
```